# Does lots of namespace like nesting of classes matter performance wise in C#?

Tags: c#, class, object, namespaces, nested

```
public class shape
{
    public int x, y;

    public class triangle
    {
        int sides = 3;
    }

    public rectangle rect = new rectangle();

    public class rectangle
    {
        int sides = 4;

        public class square
        {
            public string s;
        }
    }
}

shape a = new shape();
a.x = 4;
a.y = 3;
//print(a.triangle.sides) //no such thing
//print(a.rect.sides) //prints 4
shape.rectangle.square d = new shape.rectangle.square();
d.s = "abc";
```

It's a somewhat arbitrary example, but it shows the use of nesting class definitions in C# to work like namespaces.

The inner classes can also inherit from the outer ones and the such as well but the namespace like behaviour is the same.

Except where I made it so in "shape" with "public rectangle rect = new rectangle();" the inner classes are not so much part of the outer ones. It's more like they just all have similar names, for example they could be unstacked and the reworded with underscores "shape_rectangle_square d = new shape_rectangle_square();".

I was wondering if there were any performance considerations to this, for example in thease situations.

```
shape.triangle t = new shape.triangle();

List<shape.triangle> triangles = new List<shape.triangle>();

triangles.Add(new shape.triangle());

foreach (shape.triangle t in triangles)

func(new shape.triangle(1, 2, 3), "ted");
```

vs

```
shape_triangle t = new shape_triangle();

List<shape_triangle> triangles = new List<shape_triangle>();

triangles.Add(new shape_triangle());

foreach (shape_triangle t in triangles)

func(new shape_triangle(1, 2, 3), "ted");
```

Comment: Just an observation, nesting classes like this almost *always* makes things harder to find.

Comment: It would surely affect programmer performance.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that there is no performance-wise impact, but do you really want to have to write `shape.rectangle.square` every time you want to create a square?

Comment: The libraries that come with the language have quite deep namespaces, it's much like System.Stuff.Console.etc...

Comment: The Framework Design Guidelines proscribe this: "Do not use public nested types as a logical grouping construct; use namespaces for this." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229027.aspx)

Comment: @alan2here: Framework/BCL namespaces and types are an entirely different thing...

Comment: @BoltC : But when using nested types, (outer) classes and namespaces are as good as indistinguishable.

Comment: using a namespace gives you scope across the files and across classes. Better structure. Link in the Bradley's comment makes the sense for design pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was wondering if there were any performance considerations to this?

No. It could matter a few nanoseconds in compile-time maybe.

A class allows nested Types. This is sometimes used for (private) 'helper' classes and strongly related `enum`s. But it is about structure and organization, not about performance.

In general, public nested classes are best avoided.  Public enums are sligtly more common.

Comment: Thanks for providing some info.